# Post form in iframe

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, cross-domain

I have a webpage that contains an iframe inside which there is a login form. In the main page there is a button which when I press, the fields on the form of the iframe take values and the form in the iframe is submitted. 
After the form submission, I get a white page in the iframe which I should not get and no login is made.

However if after that I do a right click inside the iframe and refresh the page with the form, it asks me if I want to resubmit the form. I I say yes, then the form is correctly submitted.

Please note the form inside the iframe is from a subdomain. Eg, the submit button is on www.mydomain.com and the iframe has a form of subdomain.mydomain.com

Any ideas on why I get the white page after the first form submission?

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The iframe form makes thenjob ONLY when I do a refresh (iframe). It pops up that dialogue which asking to re-submit the data.

Comment: Kindly post the code, without that it is difficult to assume what might be wrong.

Comment: Please read this: [MCVE]